# Make an image that spins to a random value add up the random values

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, random

I have a lucky wheel, with a spinning arrow that rotates randomly. The problem is that sometimes the arrow barely spins when clicked on, because (for example) if the first click gives the number 400 the arrow will in fact rotate 400 degrees but if the second click gives 380 the arrow will just go back 20 degrees, meaning it will barely move. So I suppose I need a way to make the various clicks add up ( 1st click - random number; 2nd click - 1st click result + random number and so on).

My code is the following:

**CSS**

```
    img {
    transition: transform 2s ease-out;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="34-200.png" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');

    var deg = 500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 4000);

    var css = 'transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}

</script>
```

Help!

Comment: Your `var deg = `  code seems perfectly fine, what _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: @ChrisG The problem is that sometimes the arrow spins only a little, like only 20degrees, and I don't want that to happen. It needs to make at least one full rotation (360 degrees).

Comment: @Chris I didn't know that. But I think you get what I meant.

Comment: @Chris you are right, thanks. Already edited

Comment: I believe @Chris is incorrect. The biggest problem here is that while setting the `<img>` to `rotate(500)` will indeed cause roughly one and a half rotations, setting it to `rotate(480)` next will make the `<img>` rotate 20 degrees backwards.

Comment: yeah @ChrisG is right, thanks. So I suppose now what I have to do is make the varios clicks add up instead of all of them start in 0. And I have no idea how.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/y1qy9u8L/

Comment: Also, the answer to the actual question is to pick a random value of at least 360.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var angle = 0;

var blocked = false;

var wheel = document.querySelector('#wheel');
wheel.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (blocked) return;

  var deg = 720 + Math.round(Math.random() * 2000);
  angle += deg;

  wheel.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
  blocked = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    blocked = false;
  }, 2100);
}, false);
```

```css
.placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  transition: transform 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<img id="wheel" class="placeholder" >
```